# jquery: make element draggable after dropped without cloning

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  start: function() {
    $(this).height(150).width(195);
  },
  cursor: "move",
  revert: "invalid",
  appendTo: "body",
  containment: "document",
  helper: "clone",
  distance: 50
});

$(".drop").droppable({
      hoverClass: "hoverDrop",
      tolerance: "pointer",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
          var elem = $(ui.draggable).clone();
          $(this).append(elem);
          $(this).droppable('disable'); //disbles more than one draggable from being dropped
          // console.log(this);
          $(elem).draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            drag: function(event, ui) {
              $(elem).prev().empty();
            }
          });
        } //end of drop function
```

Hi everyone! I'm doing up a drag and drop where I can drag an activity (`td` element) and drop it into another `td` in a different `table`. After dropping it, I want to be able to drag that element into another `td` in the same `table` (like dragging  a class schedule around a timetable)

I have managed to "re-drag" that dropped element, but instead of "moving" it to a different `td`, all I seem to be able to do is to keep cloning the element I am dragging. How can I ensure that when I "re-drag" the element that I initially dropped, it is removed from the initial `td` it was first dropped, and "moved" to the subsequent `td`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain "draggability", you can append `ui.draggable` to the new `td`. That way, you'll still be able to drag the item was dropped, giving you free reign over each item's location.

I've simplified your example somewhat, specifically the `drop` event. I've also removed some of the `options` for simplicity and fewer points of failure. You can re-add the `options` in your project:

```
$('.drag').draggable({
  cursor: "move",
  revert: true,
  appendTo: "body",
  containment: "document",
  distance: 50
});

$('.drop').droppable({
  hoverClass: "hoverDrop",
  tolerance: "pointer",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).find('ul').append(ui.draggable);
  }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/kpmmgm06/)**

If you have any questions, please ask.